# $(function(){}) in body instead of head

Tags: javascript, html

`$(function(){})` is the the same as jquery's `$(document).ready` so I am wondering if I can put it into body
instead of head ?
I only see the act of putting script at different section of the page as a matter of executing it at different time. It is true? Can I put script in a div in the middle of the page? Will it affect how DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only see the act of putting script at different section of the page as a matter of executing it at different time. It is true?

Yes, but the script you're talking about just makes a single function call (to `ready`). The callback will get called later, when the DOM is ready, either way.

> Can I put script in a div in the middle of the page?

Yes. But again, if the script in question is just calling `ready` (directly, or via the shortcut), it doesn't much matter. I would discourage you from littering scripts all over your markup; best to try to keep the two largely separate.

> Will it affect how DOM is loaded?

Only if you use `document.write` within the script (and even then, it doesn't affect how the DOM is loaded, but may affect the content of it).

---

If you can choose where the `script` tags go (e.g., you're not writing a JavaScript library or jQuery plug-in, your script is on a page you control), there's little if any reason to use `ready`. Instead, put your script tag at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. References:

- [Google Closure engineers on when the DOM is ready](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)
- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: Thanks! That is very thorough<3

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `document.ready` is to wait till the DOM is ready, if you put your scripts just before the body closing tag or just after the html that is being modified then you don't need `document.ready` although it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work but it is bad practice. If you can you should put your scripts at the end of your webpage rather than in the head. Unless of course you have something (like a document ready function) that you need to load first.